# How to use jquery in a js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a index.php that loaded a .js file.
I have included that .js file and the jquery src source in index.php.

In index.php,I include them in :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

In this .js file, it is a pure javascript writen.
I want to use some jquery code in a function like:(below shown is only a part of script.js file)

```
    switchClassHour = function(toHour){
    targetElementHourClass = traceElement().className.split(" ")[2];
    if(toHour<10){
        toHour = "0"+toHour;}
    newHourClass = "hour" + toHour;
    elementId = "#" + traceElement().id;

    $(function() {      
        $( elementId ).switchClass( targetElementHourClass, newHourClass, 1000 );
            return false;
    });

};
```

The main purpose of the code above, is to switch the class of a div element by using the jquery function switchClass(). 
I have checked that the code above the jq code is correct.
However, the chrome browser give that error message:
    Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function

What should I do to use jquery code in that .js file?
Thank you for answering!:)

Comment: Make sure your jquery library loads before your javascript file that you intend to use jQuery on. And after that you should be able to use `jQuery` or `$` object in your file.

Comment: Well if you call jquery into the top of whichever page you are working on, and this javascript comes in below that, then there won't be a problem. You can simply use whatever jquery you wish there.

The 'boolean is not a function' error is a code issue. Could you edit and show what jquery you were trying to include in it?

Comment: @user3451203 you can edit your original question with the new info to make it easier to read.

Comment: Your jQuery dom-ready function is in an... improbable location. Make sure you know what you're actually doing when you do things.

Comment: Do you mean this??: targetElementHourClass = traceElement().className.split(" ")[2];
I know what im doing, i have tested and it shows the result which is what I need.